# Hidden Field populated in Document Ready - Value not available in outer functions

Tags: javascript, hidden-field, document-ready

I have a page which attaches a **.change** function to an input type="file" on Document Ready. This **.change** event function populates a hidden field:

```
<script>
    $j(function(){
        ...
            $j('#UploadedFile').change(function(evt){
                ...
                $j("#HiddenLiveJson").val = liveJson;
                ...
            });
        ...
    });

    function importTasks() {
        ...
        var hdnResult = $j("#HiddenLiveJson").val();
        ...
    }

</script>


...
<input type="file" id="UploadedFile" name="UploadedFile" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
...
@Html.Hidden("HiddenLiveJson")
...
```

However when I get to call the function **importTasks()** the hidden value is empty.
Is this expected behavior or should I expect to see the hidden value populated from the Document Ready? Or, am I just doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My bad - populating it incorrectly. Should be:

$j("#HiddenLiveJson")**.val(liveJson)**;

Working now!